# clicked checkbox is not checked but wrong one is getting checked automatically

Tags: jquery

I have a table with many rows, where the first column is a checkbox. and HTML structure is given below. Each check box has the same classes and the only difference is the value and the last part of the id as given below.

```
<tr class="even">
  <td class=" col-select col-massaction col-in_category " >
    <label class="data-grid-checkbox-cell-inner" for="id_2001">
       <input type="checkbox" value="2001" id="id_2001" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox">
       <label for="id_2001"></label>
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I click on the last checkbox, one random checkbox in the upper portion gets a tick mark, and it returns its value, Not the one I checked.

It is showing this behavior randomly. Sometimes the last one works fine, but some other shows are wrong.

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkbox", function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    console.log(id);
});
```

What is wrong with this??

Comment: Are you using `<label for="xx">` elements to wrap the checkboxes? Note that we can't really help solve this issue without seeing the full code which displays the problem

Comment: seems ok to me. don't be confused with multiple console logs showing on each click: https://prnt.sc/V45PCGqHzE_6 . Code working fine. So pleas provide a bit more HTML code so that we can check what's going on

Comment: Hi , Please see the edited code above.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, yes there is a label as you said. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: Potentially yes. Check that the `for` attribute on the `label` element around the checkboxes is referencing the `id` of the correct element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, checked, all seems correct.